# Jmeter error "javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property"

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using Jmeter for the first time and when I try running any of the pre-defined functions in JMS Point-to-point I see issue as below:-

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

I am not much sure on what class name has to be specified here.

Below is the info from logs:-

```
017-06-27 22:59:06,868 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JMSSampler: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:329) [ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:677) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996) [jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978) [jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:646) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:634) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
2017-06-27 22:59:06,915 INFO o.a.j.f.LogFunction: Thread Group 1-1  :  "Hello world"
2017-06-27 22:59:06,915 WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.JMSSampler: Session may not be null while creating message
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the fully qualified class name of the factory class that will create the initial context. An initial context is the starting point for naming operations.

See [javax.naming.Context class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY) for more detailed explanation (if it helps).

So basically you need to figure out what [Message Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) server you need to test and once you know at least what is being used you will need to find out correct QueueConnectionFactory and InitialContext class names, queue names and other JMS Properties.

Check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article for more information.

Comment: Excellent........ Dmitri... Thanks alot for the response. In jmeter, can I store the return value to a variable and print it. Something like below:-

int ${x}  = ${__intSum(8,10,)};

print(${x});

Comment: Of course, the function like `${__log(${__intSum(8,10,x)},,,)}` will 1. return the value where it is called. 2. create a JMeter Variable `x` with the value. 3. print the value to *jmeter.log* file. See [demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osHcr.png) and [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get started with JMeter Functions concept

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri for quick response.

These Docs and info would help me a lot :) :)